# Как пользоваться таблицей прерываний BIOS

Tags: ассемблер, bios, прерывания

Начал изучать ассемблер и не совсем понимаю как используются прерывания в реальном режиме адресов.
Таблица прерываний это 256 абсолютных (сегмент:смещение) четырехбайтных адресов, допустим нам нужна функция 03h – Читать позицию и размер курсора, записываем: mov al, 03h, потом нам нужно записать в регистры некоторые данные: начальное и конечное положение курсора и т.п., а потом вызывается прерывание INT 10H. Так вот, я не знаю сколько аргументов нужно указывать для вызываемой функции, где можно найти подробную документацию всего этого? Гугли, но так и не нашел ничего. И обязательно ли указывать все данные для вызова функции между
mov al, 03h
....
INT 10H

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H

Comment: Надо заполнять все необходимые значения разумеется. Смотрите описания прерывания 10Н: 
 http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/int_0009.php

Comment: mov ah,3   xor bx,bx   int 10h -> результат в DX & CX

Comment: Эх, когда не было еще Интернета и еле бегал FidoNet, а на компьютерах стоял DOS... — был *must have* [InterruptList от Ральфа Брауна](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralf_Brown%27s_Interrupt_List)... И было там это все, и многое сверх того...